# How to allow Java on a Firefox with Robot Framework?

Tags: java, firefox, automated-tests, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I want to run an automated Test on a Website that uses a Java Plugin.
The Problem I face right now is that Robot Framework opens a new Browser of Firefox where Java is always blocked from that Site.

How can I run Firefox with Java allowed for the trusted Site I try to Test?

Thanks for your Answers

Comment: Im sure there is an option you can add to the `Open Browser` keyword which takes into account a FF profile. I have never done it though. Look at  http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Open%20Browser Where it says ff_profile_dir

Comment: I tried it but it isnt working. Robot framework doesnt use the Settings from the default profile.